# How to get timestamp from this format (2020-09-20 12:25:01) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I have a date coming with this format `2020-09-20 12:25:01` and I need to get the timestamp from it to pass the time stamp to the date-picker, how to do that with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
const dt = new Date("2020-09-20 12:25:01")
```

This will use system's timezone

If you want to get timestamp in miliseconds, you can use:

```
const timestamp = dt.getTime()
```

If you want to specify timezone, you can add `GMT+hhmm` to the string, for example:

```
const dt = new Date("2020-09-20 12:25:01 GMT+0200")
```

You can also use `Date.parse()` instead of `new Date()`

Comment: "*If you want to specify timezone, you can add GMT+hhmm to the string,*" do **not** do that, this is not a standard string. It might or might not work how you expect depending on the environment. The correct syntax is `2020-09-20T12:25:01+02:00` You need a `T` between the date and time and the timezone offset has to be in the `+HH:mm` format or a literal `Z` to indicate `UTC`. [See more in the standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format)